# Can I reuse a socket file handle with socket.fromshare?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, python-3.x

I'm writing a file cache server to hold copies of static files for a web server. Whenever a thread in the web server needs a static file, it opens a socket connection to the cache server and sends it the result of `socket.share()` + the name of the file it wants. The cache server uses the result of `socket.share` to gain access to the http client via `socket.fromshare` and sends the contents of a static file. Then it closes its copy of the http client socket, and the thread's connection to it.

I'm wondering if using `socket.detach` instead of `socket.close` will automagically improve performance? The documentation for `socket.detach` says this:

> Put the socket object into closed state without actually closing the underlying file descriptor. The file descriptor is returned, and can be reused for other purposes.

Do I have to explicitly use the returned file descriptors somehow when new sockets are created by the cache server, or does the `socket` module know about existing reusable file descriptors?

Answer (score 0):

[`socket.detach`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/socketmodule.c#L2606) only clears the file descriptor field on the `PySocketSockObject` struct. It does not store the value in any way so that the rest of the module could know that the file descriptor is available for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why:

1. You're using `socket.share` and
2. You think it would improve performance.

You say that you're already threading. A web server is going to be IO bound. Most of your time will be spent:

- negotiating a TCP/IP connection between client and server
- finding the information on disk (memory? Sweet, faster!)
- reading from the disk (memory?) and writing to the socket

You should *also* profile your code before you go about making improvements. What is the actual holdup? Making the connection? Reading from disk? Sending back to the client?

Unless you've already done some tremendous improvements, I'm pretty sure that the actual TCP/IP negotiation is a few orders of magnitude *faster* than getting your information from the disk.